# Why does my panel drawer not work properly?

Tags: gnome-panel

I used the add to panel applet to add a 'drawer' of common shortcuts to my gnome-panel, but when I click on the drawer icon, it only pops up far enough to see one icon until I mouse over it and hover there for a second or two.

Then, it finally expands the rest of the way so I can click on the other icons.

How can I fix this annoyance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably [bug #108951](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/108951). You'll note that a patch is attached to comment #62.

Comment: excellent, thanks. Wish it would just be fixed for good, though.